# What is the appropriate term for requesting html via Ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to find the right term for the activity of 'requesting html via Ajax'. Is there one?

Comment: Easily my fav question ever, still -1 I'm afraid!

Comment: I don't see why this is such a bad question tbh. It's perfectly reasonable for people who want to know if there is a term for that specific activity. And where else to ask such a question than on Stackoverflow

Answer (score 3):

This is generally referred to as "requesting HTML via ajax".

Comment: could you shorten it to RHTMLVA.......rolls off the tongue

Comment: @Liam - how would you pronounce that? ru-h-te-ma-le-vah perhaps?

Comment: "ru-h-te-ma-le-vah perhaps" there is a non-zero chance to summon some beast if you pronounce it right

Comment: REHVA is easy to pronounce :)

Comment: Special thanks to the humourless downvoter.

Comment: Thanks, I was asking for a term, not a sentence.

Comment: @nimrod - No problem, glad I could help ;) BTW ajax has itself become verbified, so the term you're looking for is almost certainly "ajaxed". As in "I ajaxed that html into my div".

Answer (score 1):

Ajax is just an acronym for 'Asynchronous JavaScript and XML' which you probably already know.

So it really should be "Requesting HTML with Ajax'. Or more technical, since HTML5 isn't xml you could say:
"Request HTML via XHR"

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest